# Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, announcements, ip-address

From time to time, Stack Exchange makes improvements to our network infrastructure.  One change we're making in the coming weeks will include new IP addresses for most, if not all, of our public Stack Exchange network sites and web properties.

Expect the changes to start on or after September 19 and continue for a few weeks until all the migrations are complete.

Since we're sure someone will notice and ask if that's intentional, we thought we'd let you know.

These changes should be invisible to users of the website. While we don't expect any downtime or technical issues, please use the regular channels for reporting any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. If anyone has any questions about it, we'll redirect them here. Unless things start catching fire, we'll ping the relevant people if that happens :-)

Comment: When the changes are visible to users, report on Xitter as none of the regular channels will probably work ... ;)

Comment: Sorry but this really break too many things. Thanks for the heads up, but in my opinion this is bad decision to do that.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard You should read into this that we're not just playing IP address bingo for fun - when you move architecture you don't always have the luxury of taking all your IP addresses with you.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, this explain a lot. The post here says "improvements", not *changing the whole thing*. This is very different.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Sometimes we need to err toward vague instead of fully transparent, for security reasons. I just wanted to make it clear that we didn't just decide to rotate a bunch of IP addresses. :-)

Answer (score 9):

*While we don't expect any downtime or technical issues...*

Such optimism!  We sincerely wish you well, but everyone who has been around technology for more than a few minutes knows that such optimism, is well, optimistic!

(e.g. see today's post: [Stack Exchange Meta Sites are down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393106/stack-exchange-meta-sites-are-down))

Comment: It was obvious things will break, yeah. It's like breaking walls inside house as part of renovation, keeping to live as usual inside and expecting it won't affect anything.

Comment: Congrats!  You've just told the author something he already knows (anyone in the industry knows).  What would be more useful is to suggest new wording that doesn't have the problem you think exists.

Comment: @TomLimoncelli To whom is your comment directed?