# Stack Exchange Meta Sites are down

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, connectivity

A lot of meta sites have become unavailable recently (in the last few hours or so), for example [Math Stack Exchange Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [3D Printing Meta](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/). Here is the error message:

> [image]

I am using Chrome on Windows 11. The Math Stack Exchange Meta issue can also be reproduced on Edge and Tor. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Duplicated: Firefox, Win10

Comment: Note that, using Edge on Windows 10, I'm able to access both of your linked meta sites, as well as the top listed questions on both of the sites. In addition, I was just using the Math meta site a short while ago, at very close to the time of your question, with the site also working properly for me at that time.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for commenting, I noticed that its going in and out a lot, for example Math Meta just became available again on chrome (but printing Meta is still out).

Comment: You're welcome. Just after you replied, and now about 12 minutes later, I checked the 2 meta sites to find they are both still working properly. Thus, it appears the problem you're encountering is not affecting me, so it doesn't appear to be global in scope but, instead, might be due to something related to the location (FWIW, I live near Vancouver, BC, Canada).

Comment: I did see this a minute ago but it seems to have fixed itself, as far as I'm aware. Can you check again?

Comment: @Catija  also just checked again, 3D Printing is still unavailable on all browsers, I live in the U.S. so may be a location problem, I'm not quite sure though.

Comment: My understanding is that it should be transient. We're making some changes in our servers and this message was identified earlier today as a potential impact of the change which led us to slowing down our rollout. When it was determined to be resolved, we resumed the changes. While I've shared your post internally, my reading of the situation is that it should clear up relatively quickly and should be blamed on caching.

Comment: FWIW, they display properly for me now.

Comment: @CDR its also working for me too! I hope its fixed now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be fixed now! Thanks so much for bringing it to our attention and apologies to the sites impacted.

In preparation for - [Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393039/stack-exchange-network-sites-ip-addresses-may-change-in-the-coming-weeks) - we're configuring everything for the migration in Terraform and one of the wildcard certificates was missed in the initial configuration, leading to this issue.

After receiving this report internally, we identified the missing certificates and released a fix.

As a note, earlier today we identified some concerns that led to this message being shown on a couple of sites, so we paused the changes until the issue was resolved. Once that happened, we continued with the rollout.

Comment: Looks like you [missed another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393110/all-links-in-all-emails-are-broken), or something else related to the IP change. Well, it was obvious such a major change will break many things. Thanks for fixing!