# All links in all emails are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email, maintenance

The links from Stack Exchange's inbox and SOFT inbox notifications emails go through a https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ link. Currently these links are hitting an "offline for maintenance" page:

[image: error page when clicking any link in emails]

Comment: Random observation: Looks like this is the first time status-review tag is used in the first revision of a post in MSE. Anyway, thanks for reporting the bug.

Comment: @RandomPerson I created a SEDE query to see, and while rare, this is not the first time that tag was used in the first revision of an MSE post. https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1785592

Comment: @cocomac ...and the author of this question accounts for a majority of those cases.

Comment: Not only Teams, all links in all emails are broken, that's a critical bug. @RandomPerson

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I thought that only links in new emails were affected. But that's not the case. Even links in old emails are broken.

Comment: @RandomPerson yes, that's what I meant in the comment and my edit and why it's critical bug. Looks like they shut down essential part of their infrastructure, hopefully not on purpose. (Sadly, I won't be surprised if they did)

Comment: From what I understand more of a bit of reconfiguration than a shut down. Besides, I think breaking these links with no warning makes no sense, especially for teams users.

Comment: Thanks, have passed this on to the SRE team.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Could it be related to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393039/?

Comment: @RandomPerson Not much point in speculating. We find bugs, a mod or staffer verifies there's a bug, and we wait for a fix. We don't have, nor have we ever had enough view on the inside to tell.

Comment: Seems to be fixed

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz no, not fixed for me.

Comment: @Dalmarus this is not fixed, at least not for me, so maybe location based. Better not mark as completed for now.

Comment: For me the links in new mails now work, as well as the links from emails a couple of hours ago, which previously led to the offline page, now work, too.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Yep, that was on me, marking too early - the fix had been created, but deployment hadn't fully gone out yet. Sorry for jumping the gun. Should be all good to go now though. :)

Comment: @Dalmarus awesome, thanks. And get a better holster! :D

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the report. The team found the issue and a fix has been deployed. Current testing shows the issue is no longer occurring so I've marked this as status-completed.

Comment: Was this because of the IP address change?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Indirectly, yeah. We're changing CDN providers (hence the IP change), and in the process of switching, we missed an obscure configuration specific to the email link domain.