# Some Stack Exchanges sites intermittently failed to load CSS and favicon with error code HTTP 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, page-load

When accessing some sites, sometimes `primary.css` and `favicon.icon` failed to load with the error code HTTP 406 Not Acceptable. (Ad blocker and user scripts already disabled)

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Display | Network |

When opening on incognito mode

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Display | Network |

Reloading the pages after some time might fix itself, and I also can't reproduce the issue consistently.

Additional details: Chrome 117, Windows 10, South-East Asia, no VPN/Tor.

---

(Note: I'm honestly not sure if this is an issue with my network or elsewhere, but [this is the second time I faced this issue](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9652189#9652189), and it started happening very recently)

Comment: Possibly related or not: [Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393039/241919)

Comment: A 406 status code would be coming from our old WAF that we'll be turning off tomorrow, you might have exceeded a rate limit on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of this morning, the application that returned 406 codes has been turned off, and you should no longer be getting these errors.